# SDWebImage Throwing 'Too Many Arguments' Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sdwebimage, objc-message-send

When I run the app on simulator, it runs perfect. When I try to Archive to upload to AppStore I get error messages on SDWebImageManager that says `SDWebImageManager.m:244:22: Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 5`

I have gone into both the Project and Target and turned OFF the enable strict checking of objc_msgSend Calls but it still does this. I'm at a loss.

Comment: What a version of SDWebImage pod do you use?